# know how can you write the declaration for method "Init"

Tags: c#, init

I am a newbie. I want to know how can you write the declaration for method `Init` as below.

```
Role role = Manager.Init<Role>();
```

Comment: What language is this? C#?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Manager` is a class, it would look like:

```
class Manager {
    // ...
    public static T Init<T>() {
        // ...
    }
}
```